# Image format to put inside PDF's to have fast rendering

Tags: performance, image, pdf, rendering, mupdf

I would like to know which image format inside PDF's is rendered fastest. I tested mupdf code and I figured out that image decoding takes an important part in rendering time. So I would like to know if there are image formats that would not impact very much on cpu load.

Comment: Why is it important? Do you create large PDF files wit many Images? Is the rendering to slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this is really a question of what is best simply within PDFs, however:

As a general rule, I have always found that pre-rendering the image's size to the actual size you wish to present on screen is the best way to get both size and rendering speed to what you want them to be.  Simply dragging an image into a document doesnt bring the pixel count (thus size) down as most document types simply put a display size tag around the full image.  This causes the display program to have to real-time resize the image for display.  The less the display program has to real-time resize the image the faster it will display.

As for file types:
Bitmaps are generally considered the fastest to display as they (for the most part) are copy and paste the color for each pixel onto the screen pixel.  They are generally considered the biggest file.  Depending on your images, if they aren't noisy (have a lot of solid runs of the same color) then they can be RLE encoded.  I have seen many RLE encoded images that are indeed even smaller than JPEG images, but it is very situational.

JPEGs tend to be the smallest for transfer and also generally display decently quick.  As an opinion they are also the lowest quality images (look close, if you started with a perfectly clean image, JPEG compression will add noise to it unless using lossless compression)

PNGs tend to be my favorite.  They can be lossless compressed, can be fairly small if using flattened PNGs (i.e. NOT ADOBE FIREWORKS PNGs) and do produce crisp images that render fairly quickly.

So to sum up:  I would probably recommend flattened PNGs that have been pre-sized and saved to the size you wish to display on screen.